How to serialize a CT_Tbl object using pickle?
I would like to serialize a CT_Tbl object using pickle in python.
But I got:
import pickle
pickle.dumps(tbl)
=>
TypeError: cannot pickle 'CT_Tbl' object

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!
